# How to Start Timer from One Activity and Stop from another activity?

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I want to start a Timer from a class which will keep on running until i stop from it from other class. For this,
I have created class for timer and methods named startTimer and stopTimer as given below:

```
public class TimerTaskClass extends Application {
Timer timer = new Timer();

public static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 10000;

public void startTimer(final Context context) {

    Log.d("Constants", "Timer Started");
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask() {

            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            @Override
            public void run() {

             //Performing my Operations

            }
        }, 0, TIME_INTERVAL);

}



public void stopTimer() {
    timer.cancel();
}
```

What i am doing is, I have two activity ClassA and ClassB

```
 Class A{

  onCreate(){
     TimerTaskClass tmClass=new TimerTaskClass();
     tmClass.startTimer();
  }


 }

  Class B{

  onCreate(){
     TimerTaskClass tmClass=new TimerTaskClass();
     tmClass.stopTimer();
  }


 }
```

But this is not stopping my timer which i have started from ClassA. How this can be done?

Comment: Try to use fragment with Activity to do so

Comment: set it Timer in second activity

Comment: @Shane Ty for replying. But i have Activity and changing it to fragment will be a big change for me. :(. Any Other way to do so?

Comment: @Nikung Ty for replying. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Why do you let TimerTaskClass extend Application? Did you also make the necessary changes in the Manifest to really use it as *the* Application (set `android:name` attribute)?

Comment: @0X0nosugar no i didnt did anything in manifest. I did this by reading somewhere, so that this remains same in whole application.

Comment: But to make use of TimerTaskClass as your application class you need to change the Manifest. If you do so, you can access the same timer instance from every Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could change TimerTaskClass to singleton, so in both activities you will use the same instance of TimerTaskClass, it should solve your problem.

```
public class TimerTaskClass 
{
    private static TimerTaskClass _instance;

    private TimerTaskClass ()
    {

    }

    public synchronized static TimerTaskClass getInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new TimerTaskClass ();
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this.Ty for replying.

Comment: i think its a wise solution!!! because he need the same instance while he was creating separate instance for start and stop function!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `TimerTaskClass` extends `Application`. This is possible although it may not the best solution in every case, see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). To follow through with this approach, you also have to set the `android:name` attribute for `application` in the `Manifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name=".TimerTaskClass"
    ...keep the rest like before...
>
    ... keep this part unchanged as well ...
</application>
```

Now, `TimerTaskClass` will be instanciated as soon as your app is launched.

You can access it from every `Activity` like this:

```
TimerTaskClass ttc = (TimerTaskClass)getApplication();
```

The `timer` will be created as member of the `Application` instance (which is a Singleton by default), so there will only be one instance of it. So you can start it as follows:

```
ttc.startTimer(getApplicationContext());
```

If you decide that using your own `Application` object is not what you want, I think the answer by @Thror will be the best way to go. BTW in this case, you certainly should not let `TimerTaskClass` inherit from `Application` - it would not be useful and might even cause problems.

Comment: Thanx for letting me know the differences. And i have adopted Thror solutions.

Comment: @Rahul - I think that's indeed the best option here. Please don't forget to accept Thror's  answer (click grey checkmark below votes).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Activity A and Activity B each create their own `TimerTaskClass` instance. Instead, they should share an instance.

The easiest way to do this is to implement the `TimerTaskClass` as a  [Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java) so that both activities can talk to the same instance of the class.

Beware that overuse of the Singleton pattern leads to bugs that can be hard to trace and fix. As long as there aren't many components invoking methods on your singleton at the same time, you should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create singleton as below

```
public class TimerTaskClass {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 10000;

  public void startTimer(final Context context) {

   Log.d("Constants", "Timer Started");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask() {

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        public void run() {

         //Performing my Operations

        }
    }, 0, TIME_INTERVAL);

  }
public void stopTimer() {
  timer.cancel();
}
```

Now in Activity you have to do this

```
TimerTaskClass tmClass=new TimerTaskClass();
tmClass.startTimer();
```

And in Second Activity

```
 TimerTaskClass tmClass=new TimerTaskClass();
 tmClass.stopTimer();
```

Hope you understand the concept